# Question about exercise 12.17 in TeXbook

Tags: tex-core

This is exercise 12.17

> (This is a sequel to exercise 12.2, but it's trickier.) Describe the result of `\line{\hfil A puzzle.\hfilneg}`

This is exercise 12.2

> Describe the result of `\line{\hfil\hfil What happens now?\hfil}` `\line{\hfill\hfil and now?\hfil}`

The answer to exercise 12.17 reads:

> ... (In this case, TeX's rule about infinite glue differs from what you would get in the limit if the value of 1 fil were finite but getting larger and larger. The true limiting behavior would stretch the text `A puzzle.' in the same way, but it would also move that text infinitely far away beyond the right edge of the page.)

Example from the question is equivalent to this:

```
\hbox to\hsize {\hskip 0pt plus 1fil A puzzle.\hskip 0pt plus -1fil}
```

How in terms of this does one interpret the words "if the value of 1 fil were finite" and "true limiting behavior"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\hfilneg` isn't a `minus` value but rather a negative `plus` value:

```
\hbox to\hsize {\hskip 0pt plus 0pt A puzzle.\hskip 0pt plus -0pt}

\hbox to\hsize {\hskip 0pt plus 10pt B puzzle.\hskip 0pt plus -10pt}

\hbox to\hsize {\hskip 0pt plus 100pt C puzzle.\hskip 0pt plus -100pt}

\hbox to\hsize {\hskip 0pt plus 1000pt D puzzle.\hskip 0pt plus -1000pt}

\hbox to\hsize {\hskip 0pt plus 1fil E puzzle.\hskip 0pt plus -1fil}

\hbox to\hsize {\hfil F puzzle.\hfilneg}

\bye
```

Note the last two examples E and F are the same, but the point is they do not correspond to the limiting case of A-D as the finite skip gets larger.

[image]

Comment: Fixed the question. BTW, should "was" be used instead of "were" in the answer? (because the concept of 1fil is regarded here as a singular thing)

Comment: @IgorLiferenko were is OK here it's not singular/plural but rather the conditional would .. if ... were (but don't ask an Englishman about English grammar:-)

Comment: why the case B C D show nothing on the final page?

Comment: @Lucas better to ask new questions than comment on old ones, but they are all off the page, to the right like `\hbox{\hskip 100cm B \hskip -100cm}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for hint. I now relize that `\hskip 0pt plus 10pt a b\hskip 0pt plus -10 pt` is very different from `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil a b\hskip 0pt plus -1fil`. after multiplying the glue set ratio, the left and right glue of the former have a big width.